# enable hibernate app to use clustered hazelcast

Tags: spring, hibernate, hazelcast

our prod environment architecture is decided to be like this:
2 machines that each of them have 2 tomcat instances (on vm). there is spring web app with hibernate running on tomcat.
there are also 2 db instances distributed to both machines.

so, we think that hazelcast fits this achitecture well. hazelcast will be second level cache for hibernate, it will manage clustered cache over db instances.

we installed hibernate server and defined our clusters on it.
i've searched offical hazelcast doc and several sites but i couldnt find the way to configure hibernate to use this hazelcast server as L2 cache.

we dont want to change our existing app. we'll keep using hibernate as it is. is it possible? if so, how we can configure hazelcast server on our web app?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is important to understand that your probably don't want to have a standalone Hazelcast cluster/server; what you normally do is to embed Hazelcast within your application.

Like Miko said, you can just enable Hazelcast to be used as second level cache; no need to make any fundamental changes.

I also don't understand what you mean with 'hibernate server', because Hibernate is just an OR mapper library and has no concept of server.

So can you tell a bit more what you want so we can help you out?

Comment: we misunderstood that 'hazelcast server'. it is management ui actualy. after more searching i saw there are different deployment types. so, the question is  
: we will move our application to the cloud. there will be 2 instances (2 apps, 2 dbs) on different networks. i can configure hibernate.cfg.xml to use hazelcast as L2 cache. but how i can configure both instances for clustered cache? ip multicasting can be used in same network, right? i wonder how to make both hazelcast conf to work on different network. thanks.